# Click-Once connection closed because no user-agent specified

Tags: vb.net, deployment, clickonce

Can't find any relevant answer to this particular issue which concern click-once deployement for a vb.net application.

My hosting provider block any connection with blanck user-agent since a few month. And so :

```
DÉTAILS DE L'ERREUR
Les erreurs suivantes ont été détectées au cours de cette opération.
* [08/05/2018 21:51:11] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (sous-type inconnu)
    - Échec du téléchargement de http://www.**********/E-Planning.exe.manifest.
    - Source : System.Deployment
    - Trace de la pile :
        à System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        à System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
        à System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
        à System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
        à System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
        à System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
        à System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
        à System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
        à System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
            à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            à System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            à System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Exception interne ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - La connexion sous-jacente a été fermée : La connexion a été interrompue de manière inattendue.
        - Source : System
        - Trace de la pile :
            à System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            à System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)

DÉTAILS DE LA TRANSACTION DU MAGASIN DE COMPOSANTS
    Aucune information disponible sur la transaction.
```

Install is not possible. Update is not possible.

I've also tried to use Squirrel.Windows, but the sames error happens and anyway it makes my app crash all the time.

I could subscribe to another hosting provider but it will only work until they block blank user-agent connection too. I would better like to find a proper solution.

Is there a way to add a user-agent to this WebRequest ?
Thanks for your reading.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a way with Squirrel, adding custom WebClient with specified User-Agent.